# Clickable panel problem 

Tags: android

How to implement something like this in android ?

[image]

There are three different panels ( I need one to implement), I will have matrix of this stuffs, so I need first  to figure out how to draw one . I need to implement panel  (not popup) which react on click and  which contains three smaller panels 1st type ( O or F ), second id ( and change color ) and third name. I know this implement in Java easy  but how in android ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a `Dialog` for that. If you are new to Android and it's Views the [Hello Views](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html) tutorials can be useful

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html